# Read a contact Info from Account?

Tags: apex, soql

I'm trying this but only returns account id and name

```
Account a = [SELECT Name, (SELECT  contact.Email FROM Contacts) FROM Account LIMIT 1];
System.debug(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to print the children to console by accessing the object which contains them:

```
System.debug(a.Contacts);
```

Any sub-query will return a list of records under the name you used for the query, such as `OpportunityLineItems` or `CampaignMembers`, associated with each record returned from the first query. It's literally a query for each record in your main query.

To access each objects details in apex, you'll likely need to iterate over them, such as:

```
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account];

for (Account someAccount:Accounts) {
    for (Contact contact:someAccount.Contacts) {
        System.debug(contact.Id);
    } 
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that a subquery returns a collection (specifically, a list) of the child records. The child records are fully-fledged `SObjects` in memory, so they can be treated exactly the same as if they were queried separately from the parent object. Also, `system.debug()` only prints the first 10 items in a list, so (directing this at OP) if you see `<record>, <record>, ...]` in your debug log, don't be surprised.

Answer (score 2):

This will print the children in a debug statement without a loop

```
Account a = [select id, name, (select firstname, lastname from Contacts) from Account limit 1];
system.debug(json.serialize(a));
```

Result:

> 10:51:17:017 USER_DEBUG
>   [2]|DEBUG|{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Account/0014000001Hf76yAAB"},"Id":"0014000001Hf76yAAB","Name":"Foo","RecordTypeId":"01240000000MJWwAAO","CurrencyIsoCode":"USD","Contacts":{"totalSize":4,"done":true,"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0034000001TMmaoAAD"},"AccountId":"0014000001Hf76yAAB","Id":"0034000001TMmaoAAD","FirstName":"Tonya","LastName":"Bar","RecordTypeId":"01240000000MJX0AAO","CurrencyIsoCode":"USD"},{"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0034000001TMmapAAD"},"AccountId":"0014000001Hf76yAAB","Id":"0034000001TMmapAAD","FirstName":"Barnet","Fubar","RecordTypeId":"01240000000MJX0AAO","CurrencyIsoCode":"USD"},{"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0034000001TMmaqAAD"},"AccountId":"0014000001Hf76yAAB","Id":"0034000001TMmaqAAD","FirstName":"Drew","LastName":"BarFoo","RecordTypeId":"01240000000MJX0AAO","CurrencyIsoCode":"USD"},{"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0034000001TMnKNAA1"},"AccountId":"0014000001Hf76yAAB","Id":"0034000001TMnKNAA1","FirstName":"Walt","LastName":"Washington","RecordTypeId":"01240000000MJX0AAO","CurrencyIsoCode":"USD"}]}}

more readable:

```
Account a = [select id, name, (select firstname, lastname from Contacts) from Account limit 1];
system.debug(json.serializePretty(a));
```

result:

```
10:56:24.1 (9691008)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|{
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Account",
    "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Account/0014000001Hf76yAAB"
  },
  "Id" : "0014000001Hf76yAAB",
  "Name" : "Hanger Orthopedic Group",
  "RecordTypeId" : "01240000000MJWwAAO",
  "CurrencyIsoCode" : "USD",
  "Contacts" : {
    "totalSize" : 4,
    "done" : true,
    "records" : [ {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Contact",
        "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0034000001TMmaoAAD"
      },
      "AccountId" : "0014000001Hf76yAAB",
      "Id" : "0034000001TMmaoAAD",
      "FirstName" : "Tonya",
      "LastName" : "Bar",
      "RecordTypeId" : "01240000000MJX0AAO",
      "CurrencyIsoCode" : "USD"
    }, {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Contact",
        "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0034000001TMmapAAD"
      },
      "AccountId" : "0014000001Hf76yAAB",
      "Id" : "0034000001TMmapAAD",
      "FirstName" : "Barnet",
      "LastName" : "Fubar",
      "RecordTypeId" : "01240000000MJX0AAO",
      "CurrencyIsoCode" : "USD"
    }, {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Contact",
        "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0034000001TMmaqAAD"
      },
      "AccountId" : "0014000001Hf76yAAB",
      "Id" : "0034000001TMmaqAAD",
      "FirstName" : "Drew",
      "LastName" : "BarFoo",
      "RecordTypeId" : "01240000000MJX0AAO",
      "CurrencyIsoCode" : "USD"
    }, {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Contact",
        "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0034000001TMnKNAA1"
      },
      "AccountId" : "0014000001Hf76yAAB",
      "Id" : "0034000001TMnKNAA1",
      "FirstName" : "Walt",
      "LastName" : "Washington",
      "RecordTypeId" : "01240000000MJX0AAO",
      "CurrencyIsoCode" : "USD"
    } ]
  }
}
```